# Is my reasoning correct? Showing equicontinuity.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f_n$ is a family of functions defined on x $\in$ [0,1] as following:

$f_n$ = $\frac{x^2}{x^2 - (1-nx)^2}$

Now we ask whether the family of functions are equicontinuous.

Well, take $\epsilon$ = 1/2 and let $\delta$ > 0, then for any n sufficiently large we have for any x $\in$ ($\frac{1}{n}$ + $\delta$, 1):

| $f_n$(1/n) - $f_n$(1) | = | 1 - 0 | $\geq$ 1/2

Hence the family cannot possibly be equicontinuous.

Is this a legit way to disprove the claim of equicontinuity?

(not sure how the TeX parsing works here)

Comment: $f_n$ is not continuous at $x=1/(n+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $f_n\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0$ pointwise, and because $[0,1]$ is compact, equicontinuity of $\{f_n\}$ is equivalent to uniform convergence. You have shown that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f_n(x)|\geqslant\frac12, $$
so $f_n$ does not converge uniformly. From this we conclude that $\{f_n\}$ is not equicontinuous.